# cannot rename, delete, create new though I have Create and Delete file access

Tags: dual-boot, mount, filesystem, read-only

I run a dual boot pc: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. I created a folder named `Work From Ubuntu` inside a NTFS drive named `Software` (`/dev/sda9`). After that, I mounted the whole NTFS drive at boot from ubuntu by this command at /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=0D8A08CF0D8A08CF /media/windowsDrive ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=1000,uid=1000    0   0
```

So, the `Software` mounted at boot:

[image]

Now, the problem is I can't rename folder `Work From Ubuntu`, can't create files or folder inside it, can't delete. But, I saw the `Properties` and I had correct access:

[image]

[image]

I tried with:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /media/windowsDrive/Work\ from\ ubuntu/
```

It returned:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/windowsDrive/Work from ubuntu/': Read-only file system
```

I also tried with:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/windowsDrive/Work from ubuntu'/
```

It returned:

```
mount: /media/windowsDrive/Work from ubuntu: mount point not mounted or bad option.
```

At last, I applied this:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=$(id -u) /dev/sda9 /media/windowsDrive/Work\ from\ ubuntu/
```

which returned:

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

I am not expert at Ubuntu. All I am doing is searching at google, applied solution from there. I've applied all solution I got. Now, I don't understand what to do to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/windowsDrive/Work from ubuntu'/
```

is not correct. It should be (mind the `/'`)

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/windowsDrive/
```

Having write access is all fine but only works for writable media and yours is mounted as READ ONLY.

Regarding

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

You need to `umount` the partition before you can mount it.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /media/windowsDrive/Work\ from\ ubuntu/
```

Please don't. Directories 755 and files 644 is more than enough permissions. Again: this will not work on a read only filesystem.

Do a

```
umount /dev/sda9
```

1st and see if there are any errors then manually mount the partition using

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/windowsDrive/Work from ubuntu/'
```

and see if there are any errors. Linux will NOT mount a filesystem it considers dirty. If that is the case you will get a notice about running checkdisk under windows. If so do that and you should be able to mount the partition.

Comment: I've applied:
    `umount /dev/sda9`

It hasn't thrown any error. After that, I've run this:
    `sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/windowsDrive/Work from ubuntu/'`

It's been showed:
    `mount: /media/windowsDrive/Work from ubuntu/: mount point does not exist.`

Comment: Is the mounpoint /media/windowsDrive? Try that ;)

Comment: It's now showing `Remounting is not supported at present. You have to umount volume and then mount it once again.` though I unmounted it!

Comment: Though last command thrown unexpected message, my problem has been solved surprisingly! I can now rename the folder, create new folder inside the folder & delete. Thanks for your help.

Comment: cool! make an answer if you feel confident about an answer :D